# How can my Servlet receive parameters from a multipart/form-data form?

Tags: java, servlets, parameters, multipart, form-data

I have a page that has this piece of code:

```
<form action="Servlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="text" name="text1">
<input type="text" name="text2">
</form>
```

When I use `request.getParameter("text1");` in my Servlet it shows null. How can I make my Servlet receive the parameters?

Comment: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1045507

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824), in other words: just by the same API as you retrieved the file.

Answer (score 6):

All the request parameters are embedded into the multipart data.  You'll have to extract them using something like Commons File Upload:  http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

Answer (score 2):

Use [getParts()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29)

Comment: From what class is getParts() from?

Comment: Ooooh, underrated answer!

Answer (score 2):

Pleepleus is right, commons-fileupload is a good choice.
If you are working in `servlet 3.0+ environment`, you can also use its multipart support to easily finish the multipart-data parsing job. Simply add an `@MultipartConfig` on the servlet class, then you can receive the text data by calling request.`getParameter()`, very easy.

[Tutorial - Uploading Files with Java Servlet Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets011.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the parameter like this:

```
writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + urlParameterName + "\"" )
                .append(CRLF);
writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(CRLF);
writer.append(CRLF);
writer.append(urlParameterValue).append(CRLF);
writer.flush();
```

And on servlet side, process the Form elements:

```
items = upload.parseRequest(request);
Iterator iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
       item = (FileItem) iter.next();
       if (item.isFormField()) {
          name = item.getFieldName(); 
          value = item.getString();

   }}
```